# Print array from class php

Tags: php, arrays, class

I'm trying to print data from an array. The array is from a class. I'm getting

```
array(0) { }
```

instead of:

```
Array ( [0] => header_index.php [1] => footer.php )
```

The code is:

```
<?php
class TemplateModel {
    public function getTemplate($template = "index"){
        switch($template){
            case "index":
                $templateconfig = array("header_index.php","footer.php");
                break;
        }
        return $templateconfig;
    }
}
$temodel = new TemplateModel(); 
var_dump(get_object_vars($temodel));
$temodel -> getTemplate();
?>
```

What i'm doing wrong? Thanks in Advance

Comment: `get_object_vars()` returns the public __properties__ of an object; not local vars used in its methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var_dump(get_object_vars($temodel));
```

will output class member `$temodel`. There are no class member variables, so output is empty. If you want to output your array, you have to for example do this:

```
print_r($temodel -> getTemplate());
```

Answer (score 0):

My immediate thoughts are it looks like you are setting the variables in the function 'getTemplate' and that is not being called until after the var_dump.

ADD:
And I just noticed you are not capturing the return of the function. You are var_dumping the object created from the class.

FIX:

```
<?php
class TemplateModel {
    public function getTemplate($template = "index"){
        switch($template){
            case "index":
                $templateconfig = array("header_index.php","footer.php");
                break;
        }
        return $templateconfig;
    }
}
$temodel = new TemplateModel(); 
$returned_var = $temodel -> getTemplate();
var_dump($returned_var);
?>
```

If you want to set the array as a variable of the object, that is a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your object itself has no variables (properties) to be returned with a call to `get_object_vars()`.  The `$templateconfig` variable only exists within the scope of the `getTemplate()` function and is not a property of the object.

If your intent is to make it a property of the object, you should do something like this:

```
class TemplateModel {
    private $template_config = array(
        'index' => array("header_index.php","footer.php"),
        // add other configs here
    );

    public function getTemplate($template = "index"){
        if(empty($template)) {
            throw new Exception('No value specified for $template');
        } else if (!isset($this->template_config[$template])) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid value specified for $template');
        }

        return $this->template_config[$template];
    }
}

$temodel = new TemplateModel();
var_dump($temodel->getTemplate());
```

Note here if you call `get_object_vars()` you still would get an empty array as I have made the `$template_config` variable private, forcing the caller to use the `getTemplate()` method to access the template data.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not initializing the $templateconfig variable until getTemplate() is called.  And you don't call it until after var_dump().

So basically, you're dumping an object that has no initalized member properties which is why you see an empty array.